# How to print a page using Angular on a wireless printer?

Tags: javascript, angular, printing, wireless

I am trying to print a page on a wireless printer. I am using Angular as front end for my application.

I want to know how to send print commands to wireless printer using Angular.

Comment: `window.print()`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about Angular running in a traditional web browser:

You can call [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print) which will invoke the browser's print functionality.

Configuring the operating system the browser runs on to connect to the printer, and selecting that printer as the one to print the particular page on, is entirely out of your control. It can only be done by the user and/or administrator of the computer the browser is running on.

---

You may have more options if your host environment isn't a web browser (e.g. if it was an Electron or Phonegap app).